# Adding a line wrap to a column containing strings without a space

Tags: string, shiny, datatable

I am creating a shiny app with a data table containing one column with long strings without spaces (sequence). This column does not line wrap the enclosing strings and expands to the entire width of the table, hiding other successive columns (e.g. extra_column). Please guide me on how to fix the width of the problematic column.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(chr=c(1, 2, 3), sequence=c("ATCCACACTCCCCTCACACACACCCCACACACATTACATACACTCTCCCTACACACACTCCCCTCACACACACAGACCCACACACCCACACTCCCC
", "TGAAATCAAGGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGTGGATCATGAGGTCAGGAGATCGAGACCATCCTGGCTAACAAGGTGAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAAAAATACAAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAAGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATTGCGCCACTGCAGTCCGCAGTCCGGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                                              "CAAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCAGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAAGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATTGCGCCACTGCAGTCCGCAGTCCGGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"), extra_columns=c("name1", "name2", "name3"))
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df, 
                                      options=list(
                                        columnDefs = list(list(
                                          width = '10%', targets ='_all')))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1, text break

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df <- data.frame(
        chr=c(1, 2, 3), 
        sequence=c(
        "ATCCACACTCCCCTCACACACACCCCACACACATTACATACACTCTCCCTACACACACTCCCCTCACACACACAGACCCACACACCCACACTCCCC", 
        "TGAAATCAAGGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGTGGATCATGAGGTCAGGAGATCGAGACCATCCTGGCTAACAAGGTGAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAAAAATACAAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAAGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATTGCGCCACTGCAGTCCGCAGTCCGGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "CAAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCAGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAAGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATTGCGCCACTGCAGTCCGCAGTCCGGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        ),
        extra_columns=c("name1", "name2", "name3")
    )
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(df) |>
            DT::formatStyle(
                columns = "sequence", 
                display = "block", 
                `overflow-wrap`= 'break-word',
                overflow = 'hidden',
                width = "300px"
            )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Option 2 truncate text

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df <- data.frame(
        chr=c(1, 2, 3), 
        sequence=c(
        "ATCCACACTCCCCTCACACACACCCCACACACATTACATACACTCTCCCTACACACACTCCCCTCACACACACAGACCCACACACCCACACTCCCC", 
        "TGAAATCAAGGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGTGGATCATGAGGTCAGGAGATCGAGACCATCCTGGCTAACAAGGTGAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAAAAATACAAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAAGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATTGCGCCACTGCAGTCCGCAGTCCGGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "CAAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCAGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAAGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATTGCGCCACTGCAGTCCGCAGTCCGGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        ) |> stringr::str_trunc(width = 80), 
        extra_columns=c("name1", "name2", "name3")
    )
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]